# get list of object, make an operation on them, then converting them to list of objects using rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have two Retrofit requests A and B, one of them is depend on the other,

**A**

```
    public Observable<List<Image>> getImages(double count) {
        return mService.getImages(count);
    }
```

**B**

```
    public Observable<ImageDetails> getImageDetails(String imageID) {
        return mService.getImageDetails(imageID);
    }
```

the second request **B** takes an imageId parameter which I can get by image.getId()

all I need to achieve is this:

1. get list of images.
2. get each image details.
3. combine each Image and ImageDetails into third object TheImage
4. return Observable of list of object TheImage

how can I achieve something like this using Rxjava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution, if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```
    Observable<List<TheImage>> listObservable = getImages(20)
            .flatMapIterable(images -> images) // gets individual image
            .flatMap(image -> getImageDetails(image.getId()) // gets image details
                    .map(imageDetails -> new TheImage(image, imageDetails))) // creates new object TheImage
            .toList(); // collects it to list
```

You can make parallel calls to getImageDetails if you subscribe to inner observable in a flatMap like this:

```
            .flatMap(image -> getImageDetails(image.getId())
                    .map(imageDetails -> new TheImage(image, imageDetails))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), maxConcurrent)
```

Comment: I've applied same solution and I'm getting just on item in the final list.

Comment: Note that this will not necessarily honor the order of the elements (they might be reordered).

Comment: thanks @TassosBassoukos in my case I don't care about order, there is a nice article about this point talking about the difference between flatMap and concatMap. you can find it here:  http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/